# How to extend a sprache parser to cope with leading and trailing free text

Tags: sprache

I have a **sprache** parser that successfully recognizes a variety of complex strings.

I now have to find these strings if they are embedded in free text. Is this possible?

For example, "FJ21 [7-20]" and "7.2x1.2 FULL" are examples of strings that my parser can match.

I need to be able to find them within text such as:

"The quick brown FJ21 [7-20] jumps over the lazy 7.2x1.2 FULL"

Comment: can you post your code?  and what exactly do you consider "free text"?

Comment: could you post your code so that there is a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that I can test with locally?

Comment: What kind of output are you expecting from this parser? Is the text in between meaningless?

Comment: Yes, the text in between is meaningless. In this example the parser should ignore "The quick brown " then match "FJ21 [7-20]" then ignore " jumps over the lazy " then match "7.2x1.2 FULL", then ignore the rest. 
It should output a list of 2 items, "FJ21 [7-20]" and "7.2x1.2 FULL".

Comment: Are you still looking for help with this?

Comment: Yes, I'd still like to solve this.